# Point sub directory to another IP?

Tags: web-hosting, directory

We have a website that we want to keep on it's hosting - www.domain.com.

We then want to point a sub directory to hosting that is somewhere else www.domain.com/new-website.

Is it possible to have the root level of the domain to point to one hosting and a sub directory to point to another set of hosting using A records?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a better idea to use sub*domains* for this, just create another A-record for the subdomain and then you're done.

If you want to use the sub-directories still, you have two options:

Apache's `mod_rewrite` to write a subdomain to a directory, where you'd create `sub2.example.com` and it would be accessible via `example.com/dir2`

My recommended approach, however, is to use the `mod_proxy` (Make sure all of the mod_proxy* modules are enabled).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        <Location /directory2>
          ProxyPass http://remote-ip-addr:80/
          #you can have servers running on any port
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```